# Stuck with Nuxtjs and graphql

Tags: vue.js, graphql, nuxt.js

I am in stuck with v-for and iteration of nested object Nuxtjs Strapi and Graphql

This is the object I got from graphql

```
  "fotografies": {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "attributes": {
          "titolo": "Gnu Etosha",
          "slug": "gnu-etosha",
          "immagini": {
            "data": [
              {
                "attributes": {
                  "url": "/uploads/DSC_5667_a53822dd54.jpg",
                  "__typename": "UploadFile"
                },
                "__typename": "UploadFileEntity"
              }
            ],
            "__typename": "UploadFileRelationResponseCollection"
          },
          "__typename": "Fotografie"
        },
        "__typename": "FotografieEntity"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "attributes": {
          "titolo": "Rinoceronte bianco",
          "slug": "rinoceronte-bianco",
          "immagini": {
            "data": [
              {
                "attributes": {
                  "url": "/uploads/DSC_5756_2a3da50359.jpg",
                  "__typename": "UploadFile"
                },
                "__typename": "UploadFileEntity"
              }
            ],
            "__typename": "UploadFileRelationResponseCollection"
          },
          "__typename": "Fotografie"
        },
        "__typename": "FotografieEntity"
      }
    ],
    "__typename": "FotografieEntityResponseCollection"
  }
}
```

This is my code:

```
<template>
    <div>   
        <pre>
          <div v-for="foto in fotografies.data" :key="foto.id">
            <h2>{{ foto.attributes.titolo }}</h2>
      </div> 
        </pre>        
</div>
  </template>

<script setup>

  const query = gql`query foto {
    fotografies {
      data {
        id
        attributes {
          titolo
          slug
          immagini {
            data {
              attributes {
                url
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  `
const { data , error , pending , refresh } = await useAsyncQuery(query)
const fotografies = {data}
</script>
```

I got this error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'titolo')

If I remove fotografies.data and attributes.titolo I got the whole object.
I tryed useFetch but I got the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You wrote `const fotografies = {data}`, but I think you meant to write `const { fotografies } = data`.

Do note that `useAsyncQuery`, just like `useAsyncData`, returns an object with reactive properties. But `data` is a `Ref` and not a `Reactive` object.

You can refer to the data you want as `data.value.fotografies`.

Or you can make a computed property to extract the desired value: `const fotografies = computed(() => data.value.fotografies)`.

Or you could "wrap" and then "unwrap" it to get a ref to that value whilst destructuring and still keeping everything reactive: `const { fotografies } = toRefs(reactive(data));`